# Pass Variable into Image Component - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

How do I pass `markerPass.Logo__c` which is a base64 string into my image component?

```
<Image source={{uri: 'data:image/png;base64,' + {markerPass.Logo__c} + '\''}}/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the **Template Literals** by using *backtick* ``

```
<Image source={{uri: `data:image/png;base64,${markerPass.Logo__c}\'`}}/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Side note for those completely clueless like me, it seems I also needed to add the style attribute for it to render (at least on Android). Added to image component: style={{width: 66, height: 58}}